# Underlying value is correct, displayed value is ViewModelType.ToString()

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

This has been puzzling me for a while. I have a `ComboBox` in a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, in a `TreeView` (...in a *UserControl*) - the thing works, I mean, I can run a `SELECT` in the database and see that the correct value was saved.

The problem is when I load the data from the database, and bring it into view (sorry, French locale):

[image: combox shows ViewModelQualifiedTypeName.ToString() as a selected value]

...but the dropdown list contains all the expected values, and when I select one the selected value is displayed correctly:

[image]

When I save changes, again, I know I did *something* right:

[image]

...but then the minute I reload the data, everything is A-1, top-shape, perfect... except this stubborn little ComboBox that keeps displaying the fully-qualified type name of the ViewModel...

Here is the markup for the faulty ComboBox - I honestly see nothing wrong with it:

```xml
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource StdDropdown}" 
          IsEditable="True" 
          TextSearch.TextPath="Value"
          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedOption.Values}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="viewModels:POptionValueViewModel">
            <Border Style="{StaticResource ListItemBorder}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource DropdownLabel}" 
                           Content="{Binding Value}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I need to know how this is possible (and, well, how to fix it!). I mean, it's not like the whole list is showing ViewModel.ToString()...

---

The solution is to bind `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem`:

```xml
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource StdDropdown}" 
          IsEditable="True" 
          TextSearch.TextPath="Value"
          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedOption.Values}" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

---

For the sake of completeness (and if it could help understanding why one works but not the other) - the ViewModel being displayed:

```
/// <summary>
/// Encapsulates a <see cref="IPOptionValue"/> implementation for presentation purposes.
/// </summary>
[ComVisible(false)]
public class POptionValueViewModel : ViewModelBase<IPOptionValue>
{
    public POptionValueViewModel(IPOptionValue entity) : base(entity) { }

    public string OptionName { get { return Entity.POptionName; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a number representing the sorting order for the P-Option value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The sort order.
    /// </value>
    public int SortOrder { get { return Entity.SortOrder; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the P-Option value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The value.
    /// </value>
    public string Value { get { return Entity.Value.Trim(); } }

    public override bool IsNew
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

...and the ViewModel property of the TreeView item:

```
    public POptionValueViewModel SelectedValue
    {
        get
        {
            var result = SelectedOption == null 
                ? null 
                : SelectedOption.Values.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Value == Entity.POptionValue.Trim());
            return result;
        }
        set
        {
            var selectedOption = _parentGroupOptions.SingleOrDefault(option => option.Name == value.OptionName);
            if (selectedOption == null) return;

            var selectedValue = selectedOption.Values.SingleOrDefault(option => option.Value.Trim() == value.Value.Trim());
            if (selectedValue == null) return;

            Entity.POptionValue = selectedValue.Value.Trim();
            NotifyPropertyChanged(() => SelectedValue);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:POptionValueViewModel}">
    ......
 </DataTemplate>
```

Edit : SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem

```
  <ComboBox  
      SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue, Mode=TwoWay}">
        ...
  </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Good catch, but no luck. It behaves identically :(

Comment: well are you sure the class is named POptionValueViewModel 
with a big O ?

Comment: Yeah, it's a "P-Option" (not sure even the *business* knows what the P stands for!) - I'll add some code to the original post.

Comment: i think i got it post the SelectedValue and the class that it's the Type of .

Comment: I caught an edit of your answer that turned out fixing the issue - binding `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem` works!! Just put that suggestion back into your answer and I'll accept it :) Now I need to investigate the difference between `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue`...

Comment: ok , but i think this could of been possible as well with SelectedItem and SelectedValuePath i just wanted to know what the "Path" was .